# unhexlify value within a Django template

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm storing data in a database that is encoded link so:

```
my_value = binascii.hexlify(value)
```

I then want to display this information back in a Django template.

How would I go about decoding 'my_value' within a Django template?

Comment: Take a look at [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If providing the decoded value into the context is not an option, you will need to [create a custom template tag.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/)

```
from django import template
import binascii

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def hex_decode(value):
    return binascii.unhexlify(value)
```